# How to see all TCP connections being routed for hotspot?

Tags: root-access, networking, wifi-hotspot, shell

I want to see a list of all active TCP connections on my Android device, regardless of whether they terminate in the device.

E.g., when my phone is serving as a WiFi hotspot, I would like to see all connections that the phone is routing between the WiFi and mobile networks.

`netstat` doesn't show these routed connections.

My device is rooted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `netstat -tcp` and that will show you all open TCP connections.

*EDIT*

Per your comment, you can use busybox (a very handy app you can download from the Play store) and then you can run: 
 `busybox netstat -nat` to show what you need.

-Reference: [linuxquestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-check-all-open-tcp-connections-790895/)

Comment: It doesn't seems to show what I'm looking for. `netstat-nat` appears to be what I want, but I haven't found it built for android.

Comment: Answer updated to include netstat for Anroid

Comment: 1) `netstat -tcp` didn't work on Android 4.2.1. In fact, `-tcp` actually purged the output. 2) On Android 5.0, the output of both `netstat` and `netstat -tcp` remained same. I'm using this [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=busybox). 3) If I ignore 1) and 2), the output `netstat -tcp` doesn't explicitly mention the connections for hotspot but for the whole OS including all User/system apps. 4) Did you test this command on some Android device, or fired a shot in the wild here. :-) (Pun intended)

Comment: Tested on 4.4.4, 4.4.2, 4.2.2 (Actual devices :-) ). Some had busybox, some didn't.  The output was the same format for several of the devices (No UDP connections at the time I'm guessing?)  I ran `netstat -t` instead of TCP on some devices because `-tcp` would spit back an error.  All Samsung devices, Busybox version (when isntalled): v1.22.0.git

Comment: I'm still not convinced that `netstat` gives the info I'm looking for. What I want is accessible via `cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack` but it's pretty raw. `netstat-nat` uses this source and does some filtering and formatting.